# SUM of Column Virtual Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am facing this problem that I cannot solve.

I have this virtual table in power bi Desktop (made in excel just for you) where the last column should give me as a subtotal the sum of the TOTAL column, instead it gives me the multiplication between AVAILABLE * AVERAGE PRICE as it is the formula used for each row

I list the formulas I used:

```
AVERAGE PRICE = divide (SUMX (zzzAcqVen1, zzzAcqVen1 [ACQ AMOUNT AT COST]), SUMX (zzzAcqVen1, zzzAcqVen1 [QUANTITY PURCHASED]))
```

```
AMOUNT INPUT = SUM (zzzAcqVen1 [Q. INPUT]) * [AVERAGE PRICE]
```

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJjY1.jpg

in red the wrong result
in green right result

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your formula doesn't work because in total you get total goods and total amount. Instead of this try to go through each product and then sum. You can try this: `AMOUNT INPUT = SUMX (VALUES(zzzAcqVen1[A&B]),Calculate(SUM(zzzAcqVen1[Q. INPUT]))* [AVERAGE PRICE])`

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use this measure:

Calculate the AVERAGE_PRICE as Calculated Column.

```
AVERAGE_PRICE =
    DIVIDE ( [ACQ AMOUNT AT COST], [QUANTITY PURCHASED] )
```

Then Calculate the AMOUNT_INPUT AS measure;

```
AMOUNT_INPUT = SUMX(zzzAcqVen1, [Q. INPUT] * [AVERAGE_PRICE] )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for u answer.
The solution dosnt work.
In screenshot that i posted is all right except subtotal of "AMOUNT INPUT"; it should be SUM fo column "AMOUNT INPUT" rather than multiplication

Comment: Okay, I updated my solution. Please check above. You need to create an calculated column first, then build measure .